# wordpress live site : suggestion to schedule daily jobs via cpanel

Tags: wordpress, function, cpanel, cron-task

I have a wordpress site live , I would like to schedule a daily job via cpanel to feed a custom stats table. I am a new to the concept of croning job. I would like some suggestion, also I noticed that a lot of tutorials talks about a file `wp-cron.php` do i need to schedule the job in wordpress as explained bellow and then replace the wordpress cron with the cpanel cron? or I can directly create a cpanel cron?

wordpress cron

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'my_activation');

function my_activation() {
    if (! wp_next_scheduled ( 'my_hourly_event' )) {
    wp_schedule_event(time(), 'hourly', 'my_hourly_event');
    }
}

add_action('my_hourly_event', 'do_this_hourly');

function do_this_hourly() {
    // do something every hour
}
```

Comment: Don't use wp-cron if you want a true cronjob. Schedule a curl request to a wordpress REST endpoint

Comment: thanks, i am familiar with restapi endpoints , however never user curl reuest . could you please point me toward an example on how to create a Schedule a curl request to a wordpress REST endpoint

Comment: something like `0 11 * * * curl https://somedomain.com/path/to/endpoint` for everyday at 11am for a basic GET request. Pretty much crontab entry and follow https://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html for cURL commands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make a real Cron Job for your site with cPanel. First, create a file to execute your task. To do this, I'd recommend putting the file in the root directory of your account, rather than in the public_html folder.  Create a file like, `my-wp-cron.php`

```
<?php

include dirname(__FILE__) . '/public_html/wp-load.php'; // Load WP Functions
// If your path is different, use it instead.

function my_cron_function(){

    // do your cron function here

    die();

}

my_cron_function();
```

Then in your cPanel - look for "Cron Jobs" and setup something like this:

`/usr/local/bin/php /home/your_account_name/my-wp-cron.php`

If your path isn't /home/ it should show your the path to your files in the Cron Job manager in your cPanel.

Set your cron schedule as you desire using the cPanel cron scheduler interface.

Comment: thank for your help . when I use a simple update_post meta function it seems it is working however when I tried to do more compllex things I got some issue : 1) get_post_meta is not working  2 requiring classes from the theme folder is not working. also is the die() at the end of the fuction obligatory?

Comment: If you're using other global's, you'll have to load them. also if you're including theme functions you'll have to load them as well.

Comment: thank you . could you please provide example of theme functions and how to load them

Comment: can i instantiate a theme class by requiring it as follow ? 
include dirname(__FILE__) . '/public_html/wp-content/themes/cooking/config/Data/ViewsData.php'; // require a class

Comment: I think you've definitely gone beyond the scope of your original question. The answer I gave is a general answer to your less specific question. I would say that if you have additional question mark this one as correct, and then post your follow-up question as a completely separate question.